# Django objects change model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

This doesn't work:

```
>>> pa = Person.objects.all()
>>> pa[2].nickname
u'arst'
>>> pa[2].nickname = 'something else'
>>> pa[2].save()
>>> pa[2].nickname  
u'arst'
```

But it works if you take

```
   p = Person.objects.get(pk=2)
```

and change the nick.

Why so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> type(Person.objects.all())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

>>> pa = Person.objects.all() # Not evaluated yet - lazy
>>> type(pa)
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

DB queried to give you a Person object

```
>>> pa[2]
```

DB queried again to give you yet another Person object.

```
>>> pa[2].first_name = "Blah"
```

Let's call this instance PersonObject1 that resides in memory. So it's equivalent to something like this:

```
>>> PersonObject1.first_name = "Blah"
```

Now let's do this:

```
>>> pa[2].save()
```

The pa[2] again queries a db an returns Another instance of person object, say PersonObject2 for example. Which will be unchanged! So it's equvivalent to calling something like:

```
PersonObject2.save()
```

But this has nothing to do with PersonObject1.

Answer (score 5):

If you assigned your `pa[2]` to a variable, like you do with `Person.objects.get(pk=2)` you'd have it right:

```
pa = Person.objects.all()
print pa[2].nickname
'Jonny'
pa[2].nickname = 'Billy'
print pa[2].nickname
'Jonny'

# when you assign it to some variable, your operations 
# change this particular object, not something that is queried out each time
p1 = pa[2]
print p1.nickname 
'Jonny'
p1.nickname = 'Billy'
print p1.nickname 
'Billy'
```

This has nothing to do with the method you pull the objects from database.

And, btw, django numbers PrimaryKeys starting from 1, not 0, so

```
Person.objects.all()[2] == Person.objects.get(pk=2)
False
Person.objects.all()[2] == Person.objects.get(pk=3)
True
```

Comment: +1 Great answer, very informative (especially the last part...)

Comment: It would be helpful to mention that all() is a QuerySet, not an actual list.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Comment: Yea, this way it works, of you assign it to a variable. But why changes on `pa` are not reflected

Answer (score 2):

`Person.objects.all()` returns a `QuerySet`, which is lazy (doesn't perform a DB query until data is requested from it).  Slicing a `QuerySet` (pa[2]) performs a database query to get a single row from the database (using LIMIT and OFFSET in SQL).  Slicing the same `QuerySet` again doesn't do the DB query again (results are cached) but it does return a *new* instance of the model.  Each time you access pa[2] you are getting a new Person instance (albeit with all the same data in it).